# Simple Moose::Exporter example not working

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to understand Moose::Exporter, but no matter what I try, the example almost as exactly from the manual is not working.

```
package HasRw;
use Moose;

use Moose::Exporter;

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
        with_meta => ['has_rw'],
        also=>'Moose');

sub has_rw {
      my ( $meta, $name, %options ) = @_;
      $meta->add_attribute(
          $name,
          is => 'rw',
          %options,
      );
}

1;

package Another;
use Moose;
has_rw 'foo';


package main;

my $ww = new Another(foo=>"bar");
```

This is in the file `example.pl`; when I try to run it with perl, I got this error message

> String found where operator expected at example.pl line 23, near
>   "has_rw 'foo'"
>
> (Do you need to predeclare has_rw?) syntax error at example.pl line 23, near "has_rw 'foo'"
>
> Execution of
>   example.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Another* never even attempts to import `has_rw` from *HasRw*.

If you did, would have have to do so before the call to `has_rw` is compiled, so it would have to be done at compile time. Don't forget that `Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods` would have to be executed even before that!

Using `use` did all this for you. The inline equivalent of `use HasRw;` is

```
BEGIN {
   package HasRw;
   ...
   $INC{'HasRw.pm'} = 1;
}

use HasRw;
```

Comment: Ufff. And I thought I understand perl. What is the best solution then?

Comment: That one that does what you want. It's up to you whether you want a separate file or not.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `HasRw` to another file `HasRw.pm` and specifically importing it using `use HasRw;` seemed to fix the issue.

So that's it, I guess.